# Stirling number of the second kind identities

Tags: stirling-numbers

Assuming I don't know that $S(n,1)=1$ and $S(n,2)=2^{n-1} - 1$, how do I find these numbers? For the first one, the only explanation I can come up with is that a set of n elements can be broken into n partitions that are consisted of one element in only one way. As for the second one, I couldn't really come up with anything.

Any help and comments would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: If you see Stirling numbers of the second kind as counting ways of putting $n$ labelled items into $k$ unlabelled buckets each with at least one item, then $S(n,1)+S(n,2)$ will be $2^{n-1}$ since with two buckets you can put the first item into a bucket and then distribute the other $n-1$ items between the two buckets.  Since $S(n,1)=1$ (you put everything into the initial bucket used, in which case the other bucket stays empty) you get $S(n,2)=  2^{n-1}-1$

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want to look at only S(n,2) without using the fact that S(n,1)=1?

Comment: Ignoring $S(n,1)=1$ might not be a sensible approach: almost like using inclusion-exclusion without using exclusion

Comment: Makes sense, I was just wondering if it was possible to ignore that fact. Thank you so much! :)